# Which is faster, creating an array for each game object's attributes or creating a constructor With all the attributes

Tags: java, performance, sandbox, conways-game-of-life

So i have a particles in my "Falling sand" simulation game, which are stored in array(grid) and some of this particles contains information like
id  (Water, Sand etc.),  temperature and RandomNumberGenerator.

what i do to store that information is i create an array:

```
temperatureGrid[]=new byte[w*h];
```

and i store each particles temperature in there (if they have it), instead of  something like this:

```
public particle(int x, int y, int temperature, int rng){}
```

I wonder which one is faster (Note: Performance is super important, i know i should choose readability mostly)

Comment: This boils down to SoA vs AoS, apparently most games games go with Structure of Arrays instead of Array of Structures, which is kind of what you try to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping all data in a byte array is faster for a number of reasons, including cache locality, less indirection.

Using objects allows for more readable, maintainable code. If you are using Java, it means performance is not *that* of a concern. Nevertheless, the JVM produces very fast programs. The only weak area is high memory usage, which puts pressure on CPU caches and results in frequent garbage collections which slow down execution of the program. To improve performance where it matters, tricks can be employed such us reducing allocations and reusing objects.